# Sort alphabetically <option> with php

Tags: php, sorting

I am trying to sort the option value alphabetically but I'm not sure of the best way to go about it. At the moment the code lists the property titles nicely but in no particularly order. This is my code:

```
<label><?php _e('Property Name', 'framework'); ?></label>
<select id="pname" style="box-shadow: none;" name="titl" class="form-control input-lg" >
<option value="Any">Any</option>
<?php 
  $temp = $wp_query; 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
  $wp_query->query('showposts=-1&post_type=property'); 

  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>

<option value="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
  wp_reset_query();
?>

</select>
```

How can I sort the option value alphabetically?

Comment: try : 
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array('orderby' => 'title','order'   => 'DESC') );

Answer (score 1):

try order ASC and orderby title
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

```
$wp_query->query('showposts=-1&post_type=property&order=ASC&orderby=title');
```

That should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this one .

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(   
    'showposts'  => -1,
    'post_type'  => 'property',      
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby'    => 'title'
));
```